# Binary with different vectorization paths in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I wrote a floating point intensive DLL that I want to distribute to my colleagues.

Is it possible to build an binary in VS that includes different vectorization, for example the same binary chooses between SSE or AVX2 at runtime, so that I get optimal performance?

I am currently doing the branching by loading different DLLs at runtime, but I don't like the added complexity, and I am sure the cpu detection logic durable.

I think ICC could do this (and got sued by AMD for choosing the worst code path...) but I can't find the functionality in VS. Does it exist?

Comment: Loading DLLs at runtime is the way it seems to usually be handled.

Answer (score 1):

You can have mock .cpp files, one per vectorization setting.  Then you set the compile setting for each of these to the appropriate vectorization you want (instead of global project settings).

Assuming that you have an implementation file called  `algs.cpp`  the mock file  avx2_algs.cpp  would simply contain:

```
#include "algs.cpp"
```

and will compile with its own settings.

You'd also need to define a macro that differentiates the function names for the linker:

```
#define VECT(func) avx2_##func
#include "algs.cpp"
```

and then the algs.cpp would have something like:

```
void VECT(add)(.....
```

or differentiate by namespace

```
namespace avx2 {
  #include "algs.cpp"
}
```

Then you need some type of dynamic dispatch that will call the appropriate setting function.